# Long filenames in forfiles / for cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My script has a problem with long file names.

It cuts until "c:\Program"

Thanks!

```
SET directoryToSearch="C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader"
SET r1=""
for /f %%F in ('FORFILES /S /P %directoryToSearch% /M "ac*.exe" /C "cmd /c echo @path"') do set r1=%%F
echo %r1%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `forfiles`, `for` is able to to it by itself:

```
SET "directoryToSearch=C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader"
SET "r1="
for /r "%directoryToSearch%" %%F in (ac*.exe) do set "r1=%%F"
echo %r1%
```

Note: best practice is to not include the quotes in the variable value, but quote where needed. See the changed (preferred) `set` syntax (note where the quotes are)